Externalising a Jenkins pipeline stage (to a file/library?)
I've got an SoD (segregation of suties) check that is the first stage in a few of our Jenkins pipelines, so was wondering if there's any way to load a stage from an external resource (i.e. file, library, etc)? This would allow me to keep the code much cleaner and if/when that stage ever needs modifying then it can be done in one single place.
I read about being able to configure an external library, where it reads stuff from a separate repo, but this seems massive overkill given it'd literally have one file in.
Is there any simple way to do this please?
